# How to convert vertex-colored mesh for use in SketchUp?

Tags: file-format, modeling, sketchup, import

Did anyone succeed in importing a vertex-colored mesh into Sketchup? (My goal is to get a meshed pointcloud from an upcoming laserscan project into SketchUp and then publish it in Google Earth.)

For experiments, I started with this [COLLADA file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ghvsq3uqaehsex/chair.dae?dl=0) (*.dae) (found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380630/loading-a-collada-file-with-vertex-colors-using-three-js)).
I tried several ways:

- Import into MeshLab -> renders correctly colored.
- Direct import into SketchUp -> mesh is OK, but no colors.
- Convert colors into texture using MeshLab:

  - Filters > Texture > Parameterization: Trivial per-triangle (Settings: 0/1024/0/Basic)
  - Filters > Texture > Transfer Vertex Attributes to Texture (betw. 2 Meshes)
  - Export as .dae, enable Wedge>TexCoord, disable others
  - Exported file renders fine with texture in GLC Player or Open 3D Model Viewer
  - But no colors in SketchUp
- Additionally converting to Vertex TexCoords:

  - Same procedure as above, then:
  - MeshLab: Filters > Texture > Convert PerWedge UV into PerVertex UV
  - Export as .dae (enable Vert>TexCoord, disable others)
  - Exported model won't show the texture in any software I tried. Looking at the .dae file, it contains a reference to the texture image file.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: 3D Questions like yours are possibly going to be considered off-topic. There is a proposal for a 3D StackExchange site that could use your support: [3D Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics)